# Sequence of random variables / Lindenberg's CLT

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ are independent and $$P(X_k=k)=P(X_k=−k)=1/2.$$ Let $s^2_n=\sum^n_{k=1}$Var$X_k$. Is the sequence of random variables $$\frac{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n}{s_n}$$
converge according to any distribution, and if so, to what limit?

I think I should use Lindenberg's condition, but it seems incomprehensible for me.

Comment: Do you mean "Lindeberg"  ?  Do you have a formula for $s_n$ ?